# Google map divided in regions with color and in subregions

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to divide USA map into political boundaries. i.e. states and in seven Regional boundaries on Google map. Each region will have its own color. Example, California, Hawaii, Nevada, Utah, Arizona and Colorado (Southwestern US) will all be same color. Political boundaries will also be on map along with regional boundaries. On national view only regional names should be visible and no state name. On zooming in to region state names will be shown, no city name should be visible either I zoom in or out.

Can you please help me understanding that from where should I start? Links? Tutorial?

Do I need an Image to put on map as overlay.

I am really not getting it.

If you want to close this question then please help me that what is the forum to ask this so I put it there?

Comment: Usually the first step is making your own attempt at a solution, posting it, and explaining exactly how it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I need to divide USA map into political boundaries. i.e. states and in seven Regional boundaries on Google map. Each region will have its own color.

You can do this with a relatively simple [polygon overlay](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Polygons). You'll need to obtain polygon data for each region of interest from a third party since the API does not provide any.

> On zooming in to region state names will be shown, no city name should be visible either I zoom in or out.

This starts to get more complicated. Probably best done using a [custom map type](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes.html#CustomMapTypes) (see [image map types](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes.html#ImageMapTypes)) if you don't want to see features like city names.

#### See also

- [Google Maps w/ counties overlay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544041/google-maps-w-counties-overlay)
- http://maps.forum.nu
- [State polygon overlay example](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_states.htm) (for API **v2**)
- [MapTiler - Map Tile Cutter](http://www.maptiler.org/)
- [Polymaps](http://polymaps.org/) - a personal favorite alternative to Google Maps, with a really slick API

Comment: great help. Let me try your suggestions. I will get back to you for more help if i need. Your rating tells me you wont mind.