# Coloring in Google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dictionary

I want to create a Google map as here https://www.google.co.in/elections/ed/in/results but I did not find, how can I create Google map like this?

What I want to do:

1. Coloring in Google map based on any value as in the above link map Google is displaying India election results.
2. Get value on country state hover
3. Fetch clicking event

Any code sample or web link would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This map demonstrates loading data from two sources: the polygons are loaded from a public Google Maps Engine table and the data values come from a live query to the US Census API. You can use the controls above the map to select a category of data to display.

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/combining-data

For reference [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455917/google-map-divided-in-regions-with-color-and-in-subregions)